# How to apply a validator on column of QTablewidget column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have created a table in Qt designer. In the column 2 of the table, I want input from user which should be capital letters only. How to do the same?
[image: Example Table]

Here I an not able to understand which utility of QTableWidget or QTableWidgetItem can be used here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a delegate to modify user input:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class UpperDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, index, option):
        editor = super(UpperDelegate, self).createEditor(parent, index, option)
        font = QtGui.QFont(editor.font())
        font.setCapitalization(QtGui.QFont.AllUppercase)
        editor.setFont(font)
        return editor

    """def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(UpperDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        font = QtGui.QFont(option.font)
        font.setCapitalization(QtGui.QFont.AllUppercase)
        option.font = font"""

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        text = editor.property("text")
        if isinstance(text, str): 
            editor.setProperty("text", text.upper())
        super(UpperDelegate, self).setModelData(editor, model, index)
        # model.setData(index, editor.text().upper(), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 4)
    delegate = UpperDelegate(w)
    w.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, delegate)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is a workaround on the display/editor side, OP asked about limiting user input with a specific rule.